# Would Bigelow space stations work if rotated to achieve 1G simulated gravity?

Tags: space-station, artificial-gravity, bigelow

Would Bigelow's proposed space stations work if two of them are connected by a tether and rotated to simulate gravity of 1G (or how much)? Would they hold up structurally? Would there be other problems since their systems are designed for microgravity?